# Linkedin Integration Android

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

I am building an Android application which requires **LinkedIn** integration.The main job of application will be *Login* via native app and saving of LinkedIn access token.

I went through online projects, most of them were using external libraries.

How can i get LinkedIn access token using LinkedIn android library only and using simple Java class
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this code helps you out...this consist of all functionality that one can do with linkedin api:)

package com.mypackage.linkedin;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Profile;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClient;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInAuthenticationClient;

import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.enumeration.NetworkUpdateType;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.enumeration.ProfileField;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInAccessToken;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthService;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInRequestToken;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Connections;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Network;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.NetworkStats;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Person;
import com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Updates;
import com.mypackage.R;
import com.mypackage.account.Account;
import com.mypackage.account.AccountManagerClass;
import com.mypackage.fragment.SyncContactsFragment;
import com.mypackage.imageloader.ImageLoader;
import com.mypackage.user.User;
import com.mypackage.utils.PreferncesManagerClass;
import com.mypackage.utils.Utility;
import com.mypackage.widgets.CustomPopUpSocialMedia;
import com.mypackage.widgets.CustomToast;


/**
 * @author harshalb
 *This is main class of linkedin.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public class LinkedinWebviewDialog {
    private Context mContext;
    private WebView mWebView;
    private final String TAG = "LinkedinWebviewDialog";
    private static final EnumSet<ProfileField> ProfileParameters = EnumSet.allOf(ProfileField.class);

    private final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = 
            LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(Config.LINKEDIN_KEY, Config.LINKED_SECRET);
    private final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = 
            LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(Config.LINKEDIN_KEY, Config.LINKED_SECRET);

    public LinkedInRequestToken linkedinToken;
    public LinkedInApiClient linkedinClient;
    private String callFrom="";
    public final static String SYNC_FRIENDS="SYNC_FRIENDS",SHARE_STATUS="SHARE_STATUS";
    private String statusText="";


    /**
     * @param context
     * @param callFrom
     */
    public LinkedinWebviewDialog(Context context, String callFrom) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        this.mContext=context;
        this.callFrom=callFrom;
        operations();
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param callFrom
     * @param shareStatus
     */
    public LinkedinWebviewDialog(Context context, String callFrom, String shareStatus) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        this.mContext=context;
        this.callFrom=callFrom;
        this.statusText=shareStatus;
        operations();
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for using share preference.
     */
    protected void operations() {
        final SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Config.OAUTH_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String token = pref.getString(Config.PREF_TOKEN, null);
        final String tokenSecret = pref.getString(Config.PREF_TOKENSECRET, null);
        fetchInfo(token, tokenSecret);
    }

    /**
     * This method is used for access token and webview dialog show.
     */
    void authenticationStart() {
        if(Utility.isConnected(mContext)==true)
        {
            final LinkedInRequestToken liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(Config.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            final String url = liToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
            mContext.getSharedPreferences(Config.OAUTH_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putString(Config.PREF_REQTOKENSECRET, liToken.getTokenSecret())
            .commit();

            WebviewDialog webviewDialog=new WebviewDialog(mContext,url);
            webviewDialog.show();
        }
        else
        {
            CustomToast.makeText(mContext,"No Internet Connection",CustomToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param token
     * @param tokenSecret
     * This method is used for verification of tokens.
     */
    private void fetchInfo(String token, String tokenSecret) {
        if (token == null || tokenSecret == null) {
            authenticationStart();
        } else {
            new AsyncGetCurrentUserInfo().execute(new LinkedInAccessToken(token, tokenSecret));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param uri
     * This method is used for access token and asyn task execution.
     */
    void authenticationFinish(final Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(Config.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
            final String problem = uri.getQueryParameter(Config.OAUTH_QUERY_PROBLEM);
            if (problem == null) {
                final SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Config.OAUTH_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                final LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService
                        .getOAuthAccessToken(
                                new LinkedInRequestToken(
                                        uri.getQueryParameter(Config.OAUTH_QUERY_TOKEN),
                                        pref.getString(Config.PREF_REQTOKENSECRET, null)),
                                        uri.getQueryParameter(Config.OAUTH_QUERY_VERIFIER));
                pref.edit()
                .putString(Config.PREF_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken())
                .putString(Config.PREF_TOKENSECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret())
                .remove(Config.PREF_REQTOKENSECRET).commit();

                new AsyncGetCurrentUserInfo().execute(accessToken);
            } else {

            }
        }else{
            //error
        }
    }


    /**
     * @author harshalb
     *
     *This is asyntask for linkedin.
     */
    class AsyncGetCurrentUserInfo extends AsyncTask<LinkedInAccessToken, Integer, Person> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        private LinkedInAccessToken accessToken;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Person doInBackground(LinkedInAccessToken... arg0) {
            try{
                accessToken=arg0[0];
                linkedinClient = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

            //  networkUpdatesApiClient = factory.createNetworkUpdatesApiClient(accessToken);
            //  networkUpdatesApiClient.setAccessToken(accessToken);
                linkedinClient.setAccessToken(accessToken);

                return linkedinClient.getProfileForCurrentUser(ProfileParameters);
            } catch (LinkedInApiClientException ex){
                Log.e(TAG, "LinkedInApiClientException: ", ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Person person) {

            if(person == null){

                CustomToast.makeText(mContext,"application_down_due_to_linkedinapiclientexception", CustomToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                dialog.dismiss();
            }else{
                System.out.println("person info :");
                System.out.println("person name"+person.getFirstName() +" "+person.getLastName());
                //              mCurrentPerson = person;
                //              populateAll(person);

                /*SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                         .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("sync_linkedin_data","Your account synced with: "+person.getFirstName()+" "+person.getLastName());
                    editor.commit();*/

                   PreferncesManagerClass preferncesManagerClass=new PreferncesManagerClass(mContext);
                   preferncesManagerClass.addLinkedInData("Your account synced with: "+person.getFirstName()+" "+person.getLastName());




                System.out.println("hello name:"+person.getFirstName());
                if(callFrom.equalsIgnoreCase(SHARE_STATUS)){
                    new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
                        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                            try {
                                Person person = linkedinClient.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet
                                        .of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                                                ProfileField.LAST_NAME,
                                                ProfileField.PICTURE_URL));



                                //  String fullName=person.getFirstName()+" "+person.getLastName();
                                String urlMyappsco="www.myappsco.com";
                                AccountManagerClass accountManagerClass=new AccountManagerClass();
                                Account account=accountManagerClass.getAccountInfo(mContext);



                linkedinClient.updateCurrentStatus(urlMyappsco+" "+account.rank+"(Id #"+accountManagerClass.getAboId(mContext)+")"+" "+mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.abo_url)+account.userName);


            //                          linkedinClient.updateCurrentStatus("Promoter (Id #"+accountManagerClass.getAboId(mContext)+")"+" "+accountManagerClass.getAccountInfo(mContext).aboDescription);


                                //  linkedinClient.updateCurrentStatus("This is Myappsco website1:"+"www.myappsco.com");
                                //      linkedinClient.postNetworkUpdate("This is Myappsco website2:"+"www.myappsco.com");
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                System.out.println("throttle::"+e.getMessage());

                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


                                CustomToast.makeText(mContext,"Posted successfully", CustomToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                super.onPostExecute(result);

                        }
                    }.execute("");
                }else if (callFrom.equalsIgnoreCase(SYNC_FRIENDS)) {
                    LinkedInFriends friends=new LinkedInFriends(mContext,accessToken);
                    friends.show();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }


    }

    /**
     * List of listener.
     */
    private List<OnVerifyListener> listeners = new ArrayList<OnVerifyListener>();

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when authentication have finished.
     * 
     * @param data
     *            The callback that will run
     */
    public void setVerifierListener(OnVerifyListener data) {
        listeners.add(data);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void doOprations() {
        if(callFrom.equalsIgnoreCase(SYNC_FRIENDS)){
            setVerifierListener(new OnVerifyListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVerify(String verifier) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("LinkedinSample", "verifier: " + verifier);

                        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(linkedinToken,
                                verifier);
                        linkedinClient = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);


                        LinkedInFriends linkedInFriends=new LinkedInFriends(mContext,accessToken);


                        linkedInFriends.show();

                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception

                    }
                }
            });
        }else if(callFrom.equalsIgnoreCase(SHARE_STATUS)){
            setVerifierListener(new OnVerifyListener() {
                @Override
                public void onVerify(String verifier) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("LinkedinSample", "verifier: " + verifier);

                        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(linkedinToken,
                                verifier);
                        linkedinClient = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

                        //                          linkedinClient.updateCurrentStatus(status);
                        //                          currentStatus.setText("");
                        linkedinClient.postNetworkUpdate(statusText);

                        Person profile = linkedinClient.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet
                                .of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                                        ProfileField.LAST_NAME,
                                        ProfileField.PICTURE_URL));


                        Log.e("Name:",
                                "" + profile.getFirstName() + " "
                                        + profile.getLastName());

                        Log.e("Headline:", "" + profile.getHeadline());
                        Log.e("Summary:", "" + profile.getSummary());
                        Log.e("Industry:", "" + profile.getIndustry());
                        Log.e("Picture url:", "" + profile.getPictureUrl());

                        String stringUrl = profile.getPictureUrl().toString();
                        System.out.println("url test" + stringUrl);


                        Connections connections =linkedinClient.getConnectionsForCurrentUser(); 
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

                        for(Person p :connections.getPersonList()) {

                            Log.e("Name", "" + p.getLastName() + " " +p.getFirstName()); 
                            Log.e("Industry      ", "" + p.getIndustry()); 
                            Log.e("      ", "" +  "*****************");
                            Log.e("currentStatus ",""+p.getCurrentStatus());
                            Log.e("link          ",""+p.getPublicProfileUrl());
                            Log.e("position      ",""+p.getEducations());
                            Log.e("id","" +p.getId());
                            list.add(p.getId());

                        }
                        System.out.println("list::"+list);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            //          LinkedinWebviewDialog.this.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listener for oauth_verifier.
     */
    public interface OnVerifyListener {
        /**
         * invoked when authentication have finished.
         * 
         * @param verifier
         *            oauth_verifier code.
         */
        public void onVerify(String verifier);
    }

    /**
     * @author harshalb
     *This class is used for firends and message.
     */
    public class LinkedInFriends extends Dialog{
        //Activity activity;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ListView listViewFriends;
        List<Person> arraylistFriends;
        Connections connections;
        ImageLoader imageLoader;
        LinkedInFriendsAdapter linkedInFriendsAdapter;
        private Context context;

        public LinkedInFriends(Context context, LinkedInAccessToken arg0) {
            super(context);
            this.context=context;
            linkedinClient = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(arg0);
            linkedinClient.setAccessToken(arg0);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //  activity=getOwnerActivity();
            setContentView(R.layout.friends_dialog_main);
            listViewFriends=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_friends);

            arraylistFriends=new ArrayList<Person>();

            connections = linkedinClient.getConnectionsForCurrentUser(); 

            arraylistFriends=connections.getPersonList();


            setAdapter();


        }


        public void setAdapter() {
            linkedInFriendsAdapter=new LinkedInFriendsAdapter(arraylistFriends);
            listViewFriends.setAdapter(linkedInFriendsAdapter);
            listViewFriends.setOnItemClickListener(linkedInFriendsAdapter);
        }

        /**
         * @author harshalb
         *This class is adapter class used for friends.
         */
        public class LinkedInFriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener{
            List<Person> arrayList;
            public LinkedInFriendsAdapter(List<Person> arraylistFriends) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                arrayList=arraylistFriends;
                inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arrayList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arrayList.get(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arg0;
            }

            /**
             * @author harshalb
             *This is holder class.
             */
            class ViewHolder
            {
                ImageView friendImage;
                TextView friendText;
                Button friendSendMessage;
            }

            /**
             * @author harshalb
             *This class is used for sending message from dialog list.
             */
            class SendMessageOnClick implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

                int position;

                SendMessageOnClick(int position){
                    this.position=position;
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();

                    System.out.println("send message click..."+position);
                    Person p=(Person) v.getTag();


                    String idValue =p.getId();
                    System.out.println("id array list" +Arrays.asList(idValue));

                     final CustomPopUpSocialMedia customPopUpSocialMedia = new CustomPopUpSocialMedia(context,"Message");


                    customPopUpSocialMedia.setEditText();
                    customPopUpSocialMedia.setSocialMediaTitle("Visit MyAppsCo");
                    customPopUpSocialMedia.setSocialMediaMessage("Message");
                    customPopUpSocialMedia.setSocialMediaUsername(p.getFirstName()+" "+p.getLastName());

                    String storeUrl=mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.abo_url);
                    AccountManagerClass accountManagerClass=new AccountManagerClass();
                    final Account account=accountManagerClass.getAccountInfo(mContext);
                    customPopUpSocialMedia.setSocialMediaUrl("Visit my MyAppsCo App Store at"+" "+storeUrl+account.userName);
                    customPopUpSocialMedia.setFirstButton("OK");

                    customPopUpSocialMedia.mFirstButton.setTag(p);
                    customPopUpSocialMedia.setFirstButtonOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            String shareStatus=customPopUpSocialMedia.getEditText();


                            System.out.println("shareStatus ok"+shareStatus);
                            System.out.println("DoneOnClick... ok"+position);
                            Person p=(Person) v.getTag();


                            String idValue =p.getId();
                            System.out.println("DoneOnClick...id array list" +Arrays.asList(idValue));

                            //  linkedinClient.sendMessage(Collections.addAll(arrayList, person.getId()), "HARSHAL BENAKE DEMO", "my app demo HELLO"); 
                            try
                            {

                                String linkAppStore=mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.abo_url);


                                linkedinClient.sendMessage(Arrays.asList(idValue),"Visit MyAppsCo-Abo",p.getFirstName()+" "+p.getLastName()+System.getProperty("line.separator")+shareStatus+System.getProperty("line.separator")+"Visit my MyAppsCo App Store at"+" "+linkAppStore+account.userName); 

                                //linkedinClient.sendMessage(Arrays.asList(idValue),"Visit MyAppsCo-Abo",account.fullName+System.getProperty("line.separator")+visitAppStore+" "+linkAppStore+accountManagerClass.getAboId(mContext)+".html"+" "+System.getProperty("line.separator")+"Visit at"+" "+urlMyappsco+" "+"site"); 
                                CustomToast.makeText(mContext,"Sent message successfully", CustomToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                System.out.println("throttle::"+e);

                                CustomToast.makeText(mContext,"Throttle limit for calls to this resource is reached", CustomToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }

                            customPopUpSocialMedia.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    customPopUpSocialMedia.show();


                }



            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Person person = arrayList.get(position);
                //arrayList =  arrayList.get(position);

                ViewHolder viewHolder;

                if(view==null){
                    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list, null);
                    viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.friendImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.friend_image);
                    viewHolder.friendText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.friend_text);
                    viewHolder.friendSendMessage=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.friend_sendmessage);
                    viewHolder.friendSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new SendMessageOnClick(position));


                    view.setTag(viewHolder);

                }
                else{
                    viewHolder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                }


                viewHolder.friendText.setText(person.getFirstName());
                imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context,person.getPictureUrl());
                imageLoader.displayImage(person.getPictureUrl(), viewHolder.friendImage, false);
                viewHolder.friendSendMessage.setTag(person);
                //  imageLoader.bind(viewHolder.friendImage, person.getPictureUrl(), callback);
                return view;
            }


            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arrayList.get(arg2);
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * @author harshalb
     *This class is main webview dialog.
     */
    class WebviewDialog extends Dialog {

        private Context mContext;
        private String mUrl;

        /**
         * @param context
         * @param url
         */
        public WebviewDialog(Context context, String url) {
            super(context);
            this.mContext=context;
            this.mUrl=url;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);// must call before super.
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.linkedin_webview);
            setWebView(mUrl);
        }

        /**
         * set webview.
         * @param url 
         */
        @SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "NewApi" })
        public void setWebView(String url) {
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.linkedin_webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new LinkedInWebViewClient());
        }

        /**
         * @author harshalb
         *This class is webview client.
         */
        class LinkedInWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

            ProgressDialog dialog;
            LinkedInWebViewClient(){
                dialog=new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                dialog.show();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                System.out.println("onPageFinished URL :"+url);
                authenticationFinish(Uri.parse(url));
                //          doOprations();
            }


            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

                System.out.println("onReceivedError errorCode :"+errorCode +" description : "+description);

                System.out.println("onReceivedError failingUrl :"+failingUrl);

                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                    SslError error) {
                if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

                System.out.println("onReceivedSslError error :"+error.getPrimaryError());
                super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            }



            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains(Config.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                    for (OnVerifyListener d : listeners) {
                        // call listener method
                        d.onVerify(verifier);
                    }
                    cancel();
                } else if (url
                        .contains("www.mypackage.com")) {
                    cancel();
                } else {
                    Log.i("LinkedinSample", "url: " + url);
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Config is a file to maintain all constants...just if anyone needs to know...

Comment: I can't find PreferncesManagerClass here

Comment: PreferncesManagerClass is my custom class to store my shared preferences.You can create you own class.It is just normal; share preferences

Comment: What is AccountManagerClass ?

Comment: It is just a class where database and other user details are managed.Simply ,its just a database class consisting methods related to database.